# simple_html_dom get td with an input matching

Tags: php, html, dom

Using simple_html_dom I am trying to get all td with the inner-text value 'used'.
I have tried doing the following with no luck.

**php**

```
if($input = $row->find('td[value^=used]',10)){                      
    echo $input;
}
```

**html**

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>status</td>
      <td>condition</td>
      <td>new</td>
      <td>used</td>
      <td>used</td>
      <td>new</td>
      <td>used</td>
      <td>new</td>
      <td>used</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why not just use jQuery .text() and checking with if statement?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish at the end?

Comment: I only want to do it in php, I can use if and else statements but im hoping that this can be done using attribute filters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get TD value using attribute selectors, because inner text is not an attribute.

Try this:

```
$str = 'YOUR HTML HERE';
$html = str_get_html($str);
foreach($html->find('td') as $row)
{
   if(strpos($row->innertext, 'used') !== false)
   {
      echo $row->innertext;
   }
}
```